# Multiple project for a Prism application

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I would like to create a new Prism/Xamarin.Forms application but I want to create more than 1 portable project.

What I would like to achieve is the following :

- **MyProject.Models** : a portable project that contains the business objects (the models).
- **MyProject.ViewModels** : a portable project that contains the viewmodels (references *MyProject.Models*).
- **MyProject.Views** : a portable project that contains the views (references *MyProject.ViewModels*).
- **MyProject.Droid**, **MyProject.UWP** : the executable projects.

Is this organisation possible in a Prism solution ? Will the templates work in this setup ?

In fact, I try to convert a MvvmLight project to Prism and it's how my solution is currently done.

Many thanks in advance for your answers,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work just fine.  It doesn't matter how you have your projects structured.  When you register your pages for navigation, just make sure you use the explicit `RegitserTypeForNavigation<View, ViewMOdel>` method.